# Django admin 'Post' object has no attribute 'publish'

Tags: python, django, nanoboxio

I want to create admin backend with django

modules/blog/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Post)
```

I except to Add new blog post content when i click SAVE

```
AttributeError at /admin/blog/post/add/
'Post' object has no attribute 'publish'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://ilkblog.dev:8000/admin/blog/post/add/
Django Version: 1.11.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Post' object has no attribute 'publish'
Exception Location: /data/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in _perform_date_checks, line 1146
Python Executable:  /data/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path:    
['/app/app',
 '/data/lib/python36.zip',
 '/data/lib/python3.6',
 '/data/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/data/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 1 Dec 2017 22:36:08 +0000
```

Comment: Did you make sure `Post` model has `publish` attribute? :) Copy you model declaration to the question.

Comment: Have you made any model changes? if yes, did you run migrations after that?